# Query between two timestamp date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to show my downloads query between today and one weeks ago, here is my query

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS d_count, 
        d_timestamp 
    FROM dl_table 
    WHERE id = 'someid'
        AND d_timestamp BETWEEN 1389830400 AND 1389260583 
    GROUP BY d_timestamp 
    ORDER BY d_timestamp ASC LIMIT 7;
```

The above query didn't work correctly and return me a null column or return me 7 column with 1 value in `d_coun`t which is completely wrong!!! Where is the problem ?

Any ideas?

**Notice:**

`1389830400` equal to today timestamp which I get it via `strtotime("today");`.

`1389260583` equal to -1 week ago timestamp which I get it via `strtotime("-7 day");`.

`d_timestamp` is an integer column.

Comment: Convert `d_timestamp` field to shorttime before comparision

Comment: @SuyashKhandwe Can you give me an example?

Comment: why do you have to use GROUP BY?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Because I want to group by date, for example see that yesetrday download was 5 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id) AS downloads,
  FROM_UNXTIME(d_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day
FROM dl_table
WHERE id = 'someid'
AND d_timestamp BETWEEN 1389830400 AND 1389260583 
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

This should work. Formatting the timestamp is more readable, and it makes 100% sure you group by the day, even if the timestamp doesn't match 00:00 exactly (for whatever reason that could be).

Comment: Thanks, It's work - is it possible to show all rows between one day before and one weeks ago, Because I don't want tho show today downloads until 12:00 AM?

Comment: Just adjust your second timestamp, which means `strtotime("today");` becomes `strtotime("-1 day");`.

Comment: One more question - it's working but it's confuse me for a bit, when I make time with `FROM_UNXTIME` the last day is not true, for example if toady equal to 16 January and I have a row in my table with today date `FROM_UNXTIME` show me 15 January while the date of other row is true!

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean exactly, could you try to explain it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query as it seems there some problem with d_timestamp column values 
    `SELECT COUNT(1) AS d_count, d_timestamp FROM dl_table WHERE id = 'someid'
    AND CAST(d_timestamp AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 1389830400 AND 1389260583 
    GROUP BY d_timestamp ORDER BY d_timestamp ASC LIMIT 7;`